# php If statement based on level of dirTree

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I have a array that reflected the structure of a site. I am trying to perform an if statement based on the level I am on:

Running the simple test:

```
<?php if ($dirTree[0]){echo "level1";}?>
<?php if ($dirTree[1]){echo "level2";}?>
```

Checks correctly and returns the level, but as $dirTree[0] is present on the $dirTree[1] check both levels are echoed out.

Is there anyway to run the if statement to pin point active level only?

Contents of $dirTree at level 2 (level1 and level2 echoed):

```
Array
(
    [0] => CategoryItem Object
        (
            [id] => 200139
            [isCategory] => 1
            [conceptID] => 200139
            [preferred] => 1
            [obsolete] => 
            [type] => 
            [addedInVersion] => 0.05
            [lastUpdatedInVersion] => 0.05
            [AToZ] => 
            [name] => Council tax
            [scopeNotes] => 
            [historyNotes] => Added in 0.05
            [broaderItems] => Array
                (
                )

            [narrowerItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200180
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                    [1] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200181
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                    [2] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200182
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                    [3] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200248
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                    [4] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200249
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                    [5] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200250
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                    [6] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200251
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                )

            [relatedItems] => Array
                (
                )

            [useItem] => -1
            [shortcut] => 
        )

    [1] => CategoryItem Object
        (
            [id] => 200181
            [isCategory] => 1
            [conceptID] => 200139
            [preferred] => 1
            [obsolete] => 
            [type] => 
            [addedInVersion] => 0.05
            [lastUpdatedInVersion] => 0.05
            [AToZ] => 
            [name] => Money off your bill
            [scopeNotes] => 
            [historyNotes] => Added in 0.05
            [broaderItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ReferenceItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => 200139
                            [default] => 1
                            [type] => BROADERITEM
                        )

                )

            [narrowerItems] => Array
                (
                )

            [relatedItems] => Array
                (
                )

            [useItem] => -1
            [shortcut] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: How do you determine which level is active?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the structure of $dirTree and what's in it? You mention that it's multi-dimensional but in the example we can only see a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @James Waddington @ ziGi I have updated with the contents of $dirTree

Comment: Would it follow that the last element in the array is always the active one? ie. if there was a third level but you were still at the second level, would that array still be as above?

Comment: @James Waddington Yes, that last element is the active one, and if there was another level and you were on the second level the above would be displayed.

Comment: $active = $dirTree[count($dirTree) - 1]; should work then I think?

Comment: @James Waddington This return the array only for that level, but not sure how I would implement this into the if statement, seem to always return 1 (i think). I have a php page that is used for all web pages but I need the content to be different depending on what level of the nav I am. Home section ($dirTree[0]) echo A, sub section ($dirTree[1]) echo B etc. Maybe active will work but I'm just missing it.

Comment: If I understand right then count($dirTree) will tell you what level you're at. It just tells you how many elements there are in the array. So it would give you 2 for the above.

Comment: @JamesWaddington $active = count($dirTree); done the trick for me, thanks a lot for your help! much appreciated.

Comment: @Rizier123 Sure I have put the above in to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the last element in the array is always the active level, the active level should be the same as the size of the array:

```
$active = count($dirTree);
```